# Character is inclined to the sides of the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm colliding with a normal perspective behavior.
In my 2.5D scenes where I use a background image in a 3D space I have to lift up and rotate the camera to give the right perspective to the 3D character.
Unfortunately, this kind of perspective causes the inclination of the character when it is on the sides of the screen.
In the many forums I visited I could not find anything about it.
Do you think that there are no solutions other than to work in an orthogonal projection and to attach a script to the character to resize it?

Answer (score 0):

if your character should be visible like an 2D game element just change the Camera from Perspective to Orthogonal :) (the view height can than be adjusted with the size slider)

Comment: Yes, this is the most direct way but so I lose the character's scaling and I have to attack a script to get the scale. But supposing I was in 3D how can this inclination be corrected?

Comment: all other  options will you also lead to edit / create scripts.
You could create a second camera that only renders the player and than attach it to the player, so the camera will be always on top of the player. the other camera will render the rest of the scene without the player.

But why not use Orthogonal? for your player/camera movement you have already a script. instead to raise/lower the y axis value just change the camera size.